# Combining cells and removing duplicates in CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Here is my CSV test data.
[image]

I am using the following VBA code to look for duplicates, then combine all data in the second cell of each row into the second cell of the first unique record (row).

```vb
Sub CombineAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim combinedData As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Set the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Create a dictionary to store combined data for each unique value in column A
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Loop through the rows
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if the value in column A is already in the dictionary
        If dict.Exists(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            ' If duplicate, combine the value from another column (let's say column B)
            combinedData = dict(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) & " | " & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            dict(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) = combinedData
        Else
            ' If not a duplicate, add to the dictionary with the original values from columns A and B
            dict.Add ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Clear the existing data in the worksheet
    ws.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Output the unique values and combined data to the worksheet
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

It nearly works, but it does not include the 'Text1' from the first row. Only the data from the duplicate rows.

The output:
[image]

What I'm after:
[image]

The second issue is this works when I insert a module with this code into the CSV I am working on, but if I save the module in my PERSONAL.xlsb workbook and use it on a new CSV I open, I get:

> Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

in the lines

```
 ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
 ws.Cells(1, 2).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change `For i = 2` to `For i = 1` to include the first row
- `Set ws = ActiveSheet` to manipulate the data on active sheet

```vb
Sub CombineAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim combinedData As String
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' **
    ' Set the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Create a dictionary to store combined data for each unique value in column A
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Loop through the rows
    For i = 1 To lastRow ' **
        ' Check if the value in column A is already in the dictionary
        If dict.Exists(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            ' If duplicate, combine the value from another column (let's say column B)
            combinedData = dict(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) & " | " & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            dict(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) = combinedData
        Else
            ' If not a duplicate, add to the dictionary with the original values from columns A and B
            dict.Add ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
    Next i
    ' Clear the existing data in the worksheet
    ws.Cells.Clear
    ' Output the unique values and combined data to the worksheet
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Resize(dict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    ' Cleanup
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

*Update:*

> Question:  I have columns A to P, I want to preserve everything in Columns A to H, and J to P, but merge Column I where there are duplicates in Column A

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CombineAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim combinedData As String
    Dim arrData, arrRes()
    Const MERGE_COL = 9 '  column I
    Const COL_CNT = 16 '  column A:P
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' **
    ' Set the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arrData = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lastRow, MERGE_COL)).Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To lastRow, 0)
    ' Create a dictionary to store combined data for each unique value in column A
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Loop through the rows
    For i = 1 To lastRow ' **
        ' Check if the value in column A is already in the dictionary
        If dict.Exists(arrData(i, 1)) Then
            ' If duplicate, combine the value from MERGE_COL
            combinedData = dict(arrData(i, 1)) & " | " & arrData(i, MERGE_COL)
            dict(arrData(i, 1)) = combinedData
        Else
            ' If not a duplicate, add to the dictionary with the original values from columns A and MERGE_COL
            dict.Add arrData(i, 1), arrData(i, MERGE_COL)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update MERGE_COL ( col I )
    For i = 1 To lastRow ' **
        arrRes(i, 0) = dict(arrData(i, 1))
    Next
    ' Output the unique values and combined data to the worksheet
    ws.Cells(1, MERGE_COL).Resize(lastRow, 1).Value = arrRes
    ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lastRow, COL_CNT)).RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=Array(1, MERGE_COL), Header:=xlNo
    ' Cleanup
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - I always overlook the obvious. 1 further question though - If I am to use this in a CSV with 16 columns and still look for duplicates in column A, but combining the data in cell 9 (column I) then is this code still applicable? I have tried modifying without any success. Thanks, K

Comment: Yes,  change `Cells(i, 2)` to `Cells(i, 9)`

Comment: yes I already tried that but it deletes all the other columns and re-writes using only columns 1 and 2
Guessing it has something to do with the  ' Output the unique values and combined data to the worksheet section
And this bit... ' If not a duplicate, add to the dictionary with the original values from columns A and B

Comment: `ws.Cells.Clear` clear all data on sheet. What's your expected output? It may be difficult to clarify by words. You can edit your post to share a screenshot. Or create a new post [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: So, I want to apply the same principles is I have a larger CSV with anything up to 16 columns. I'll always be looking for duplicates in Column A, preserving all other columns except one (in my first example it was column B).
So if I have columns A to P, I want to preserve everything in Columns A to H, and J to P, but merge Column I where there are duplicates in Column A

Comment: I would say it is totally differenct scenario. Of course, it's doable.

Comment: Please check the updated code.

Comment: Legendary! I had just played about and got the below to work too:

Answer (score 0):

```vb
    Sub CombineAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim combinedDataDict As Object
    Dim inputData As Variant
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Set the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Read the entire range into an array for efficiency
    inputData = ws.Range("A1:P" & lastRow).Value
    
    ' Create a dictionary to store combined data for each unique value in column A
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Create a dictionary to store combined data in column 9 for each unique value in column A
    Set combinedDataDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Loop through the rows
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Check if the value in column A is already in the main dictionary
        If dict.Exists(inputData(i, 1)) Then
            ' If duplicate, combine the value from column 9
            combinedDataDict(inputData(i, 1)) = combinedDataDict(inputData(i, 1)) & " | " & CStr(inputData(i, 9))
        Else
            ' If not a duplicate, add to the main dictionary with the entire row
            dict.Add inputData(i, 1), Join(Application.index(inputData, i, 0), ", ")
            ' Initialize the combined data for column 9
            combinedDataDict(inputData(i, 1)) = CStr(inputData(i, 9))
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Clear the existing data in the worksheet
    ws.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Output the unique values and combined data to the worksheet
    Dim outputData() As Variant
    ReDim outputData(1 To dict.Count, 1 To UBound(inputData, 2))

    Dim index As Long
    index = 1

    For Each key In dict.Keys
        ' Split the string back into an array
        Dim rowData As Variant
        rowData = Split(dict(key), ", ")
        
        ' Copy columns
        For j = 1 To UBound(inputData, 2)
            ' If the current column is 9, use the combined data from the dictionary
            If j = 9 Then
                outputData(index, j) = combinedDataDict(key)
            Else
                outputData(index, j) = rowData(j - 1)
            End If
        Next j
        
        index = index + 1
    Next key

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(dict.Count, UBound(inputData, 2)).Value = outputData

    ' Cleanup
    Set dict = Nothing
    Set combinedDataDict = Nothing
End Sub
```